# How to use Google Drive v3 API via Python API to restrict editors from sharing a spreadsheet?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, gspread

I'm trying to figure out how to programmatically in Python implement the solution described [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494893?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) for *Prevent others from sharing your shared files* (using Google Drive API v3).

I programmatically create a Google spreadsheet as follows:

```py
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from googleapiclient import discovery

get_credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict
credentials = get_creds(keyfile_dict=keyfile_dict, scopes=scopes)

service_sheets = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
service_drive = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

# create sheet
body = {'properties': {'title': 'this is my spreadsheet title'}}
response_create = service_sheets.spreadsheets().create(body=body).execute()
```

But this spreadsheet is owned by my developer account and I can't edit or even view it.  I then want to give myself write permission, which I do as follows:

```py
# change permission
new_permission_w = {
    'value': 'MY_GMAIL_NAME@gmail.com',
    'emailAddress': 'MY_GMAIL_NAME@gmail.com',
    'type': 'user',
    'role': 'writer'
}
perms = service_drive.permissions()
response_perm = (perms
                 .create(fileId=response_create['spreadsheetId'],
                         body=new_permission_w,
                         sendNotificationEmail=False,
                         useDomainAdminAccess=False,
                         transferOwnership=False)
                 .execute())
```

I want to prevent people I share it with from being able to share it with other people.  It looks like there's a way to do this via the API, as indicated here: [Use Google Drive API to change link sharing permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34646171/use-google-drive-api-to-change-link-sharing-permissions/34650212) but I can't see how to do it in Python.  I tried changing the perms dict to

```py
new_permission_w = {
    'value': 'MY_GMAIL_NAME@gmail.com',
    'emailAddress': 'MY_GMAIL_NAME@gmail.com',
    'type': 'user',
    'role': 'writer',
    'setWritersCanShare': False
}
```

(i.e., adding `'setWritersCanShare': False` to the dict) but the API call seems to ignore the `'setWritersCanShare'` key.  I also tried changing the API call to

```py
response_perm = (perms
                 .create(fileId=response_create['spreadsheetId'],
                         body=new_permission_w,
                         sendNotificationEmail=False,
                         useDomainAdminAccess=False,
                         setWritersCanShare=False,
                         transferOwnership=False)
                 .execute())
```

but I get `TypeError: Got an unexpected keyword argument "setWritersCanShare"`.

I also looked to see if there was a [gpsread](https://gspread.readthedocs.io) solution for this, but couldn't find one.

I'm at a loss.  How can I use the API via python to programmatically prevent editors from sharing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to modify the property of `writersCanShare` to `False` using Python.
- You can use Drive API.
- Owner of the file you want to modify the property is you.

If my understanding is correct, how about using the method of files.update in Drive API?

#### Sample script:

```
body = {'writersCanShare': False}
res = service_drive.files().update(fileId=response_create['spreadsheetId'], body=body).execute()
```

#### Reference:

- [files.update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update)

If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.